OpenGraph meta tag for social share works on Facebook and Twitter but not on Linkedin
I am developing a social share functionality for a website but I am encountering issues only for Linkedin.
An example of the url would be:
https://collaudo.pugliadigitallibrary.it/entities/news/fe9574a1-5ee4-4d02-bc2e-f853e20f9af4
I can see that all the meta tag are set and have the proper value but I can't understand why only Linkedin is not able to see them.
The only page where the post inspector is able to find an image is the home:
https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/inspect/https:%2F%2Fcollaudo.pugliadigitallibrary.it%2Fhome
Home inspect results
but is not the image specified in the meta tag (same goes for the description).
Can anyone spot what I'm missing or doing wrong?
I am trying to inspect pages with Linkedin post inspector but I can't visualize the image or some other tags.
I would like to be able to see the data of the meta tags reflected in what Linkedin inspector finds.
